Will my custom gate actually spin when I run it on real hardware?
I am trying to create a custom gate using Qiskit Pulse and use it in my quantum circuit. Below is the code I have written so far.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Sampler
from qiskit import pulse
from qiskit.pulse.library import Gaussian
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeValencia

# Load saved IBMQ credentials
service = QiskitRuntimeService()

# Select the least busy backend
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)

# Define a custom pulse for the X gate using a Gaussian waveform
with pulse.build(backend, name='x_pulse') as x_q0:
    pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=128, amp=0.1, sigma=16), pulse.drive_channel(0))

# Create a quantum circuit and use the custom X gate
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 0)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Add the custom calibration for the X gate
qc.add_calibration('x', [0], x_q0)

# Transpile the circuit with the custom pulse definition
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
qc = passmanager.run(qc)

# Print the basis gates of the backend to verify
print(backend.configuration().basis_gates)

# Draw the circuit
qc.draw('mpl', idle_wires=False)

 
 
with pulse.build(backend, name='hadamard') as h_q0:
    pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=128, amp=0.1, sigma=16), pulse.drive_channel(0))

from qiskit import schedule

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 0)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

qc.add_calibration('x', [0], h_q0)

from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
qc = passmanager.run(qc)


print(backend.configuration().basis_gates)
qc.draw('mpl', idle_wires=False)


job = backend.run(qc shots=500,
    meas_level=1,
    meas_return="single",) 

When I enter IBMq directly and look at the job queue, I don't know if it is working properly because the X gate I customized as follows is not entered.

